# GnuPG, Prompt for passphrase from bash script

Tags: bash, gpg

how can I prompt for passphrase from bash script?

I get this error message: `problem with the agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="/home/user/elist.txt"
while IFS= read -r file
do
    tar czf "$file".tar.gz "$file"
    gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --no-symkey-cache --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 "$file".tar.gz
done < "$fname"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message you are showing, but a couple of issues I see are: 1) `--passphrase-fd 0` means reading the passphrase from the `"$fname"` file - is this intended? Or are you trying to read it interactively from the command line? 2) `man gpg` states that, since version 2.0, `--passphrase-fd` is only effective if the `--batch` option is also given (and, apparently, since version 2.1, `--pinentry-mode loopback` is required too).

Comment: I'd like to show a prompt for a password.

Answer (score 5):

Given `--passphrase-fd 0`, `gpg` is trying to read the passphrase from the `"$fname"` file — because, inside the `while` loop, that is what file descriptor `0` is redirected from.
You have some options to make it work:

- Wrap the whole loop in curly braces, duplicate standard input to a new file descriptor and use it as `--passphrase-fd`'s argument:

  ```bsh
  fname="/home/user/elist.txt"
  {
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        tar czf "$file".tar.gz -- "$file"
        gpg --passphrase-fd 3 --no-symkey-cache --symmetric --batch \
          --cipher-algo AES256 --pinentry-mode loopback -- "$file".tar.gz
    done < "$fname"
  } 3<&0
  ```
- Explicitly open a new file descriptor for `elist.txt` and redirect `read`'s standard input from it (instead of redirecting that of the whole loop):

  ```bsh
  exec 3<"/home/user/elist.txt"
  while <&3 IFS= read -r file
  do
      tar czf "$file".tar.gz -- "$file"
      gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --no-symkey-cache --symmetric --batch \
        --cipher-algo AES256 --pinentry-mode loopback -- "$file".tar.gz
  done
  exec 3<&-
  ```
- Explicitly open a new file descriptor for `/dev/tty` and use it in place of `0` as the argument to the `--passphrase-fd` option (this is fine if your script is run interactively from a terminal; it may not work as intended if the passphrase is meant to come from something else):

  ```bsh
  fname="/home/user/elist.txt"
  exec 3</dev/tty
  while IFS= read -r file
  do
      tar czf "$file".tar.gz -- "$file"
      gpg --passphrase-fd 3 --no-symkey-cache --symmetric --batch \
        --cipher-algo AES256 --pinentry-mode loopback -- "$file".tar.gz
  done < "$fname"
  exec 3<&-
  ```

  As a more concise alternative, you can redirect standard input from `/dev/tty` for `gpg` only, using `0</dev/tty gpg --passphrase-fd 0 ...`, avoiding the need for the `exec` commands.
- Assuming you have a properly configured `gpg-agent` (for instance, on some Linux distributions the agent is a socket-activated systemd service that uses `pinentry` to interact with the user and works out of the box both in virtual terminals and in graphical sessions), simply avoid using `--passphrase-fd`:

  ```bsh
  fname="/home/user/elist.txt"
  while IFS= read -r file
  do
      tar czf "$file".tar.gz -- "$file"
      gpg --no-symkey-cache --symmetric \
        --cipher-algo AES256 -- "$file".tar.gz
  done < "$fname"
  ```

Note that I added `--batch` and `--pinentry-mode loopback` to the `gpg` command line where `--passphrase-fd` is used because, quoting [the manual](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html#GPG-Esoteric-Options),

> ... since Version 2.0 this passphrase is only used if the option `--batch` has also been given. Since Version 2.1 the `--pinentry-mode` also needs to be set to `loopback`.